# How do I show which item in the Menu List is selected with Material UI React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to dynamically style the menu list items based on setting the `selected` prop to true or false.

I am trying to use the `onClick` method and to read the `event.target.name`, change the state of the `value` provided by each menu item and then finally use the `selected` prop to check if the value is true or false. For some reason, it is not picking up the `event.taget.name` that I am trying to log.

Above render:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    notFound: false,
    value: false,
    anchorEl: null,
    industry: ''
  };
}

handleIndustriesSelect = event => {
  this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  console.log('target',event.target.name)
  this.handleIndustriesClose()
}
```

Below render

```
<Menu
  id="industries-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  onClose={this.handleIndustriesClose}
  MenuListProps={{
    name: 'industry'
  }}
>
  <MenuItem value={'aerospace'} selected={this.state.industry === 'aerospace'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/aerospace'>Aerospace</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/automotive'>Automotive</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/energy'>Energy</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/industrial'>Industrial</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/marine'>Marine</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/medical-technologies'>Medical Technologies</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/tool-manufacturers'>Tool Manufacturers</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/mixed-parts'>Mixed Parts</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/watch'>Watch</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Look at your function (handleIndustriesSelect). Looks like you have a typo. Change it to: handleIndustriesSelect = (event)=>{ }

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually the same thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `state` to select the menu item because the states are not kept when you click the menu items every time.
When you click the menu item, it is supposed to change the url and the component will be re-rendered.

So the solution is to check if the current location(url) is matched with the menu item's target url. If matched, the `selected` prop of menu item should be true. In order to get the current location as a prop in the component, you will need to use `withRouter` HOC of `react-router`.

Here is a full code that verify how this works.
https://codesandbox.io/s/j432ox8255

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
      notFound: false,
      value: false,
      anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleIndustriesOpen = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleIndustriesClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { location: { pathname } } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
       <Button
          aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'industries-menu' : null}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleIndustriesOpen}
        >
          Open Menu
        </Button>
        <Menu
          id="industries-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleIndustriesClose}
          MenuListProps={{
            name: 'industry'
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/aerospace'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/aerospace'>Aerospace</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/automotive'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/automotive'>Automotive</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/energy'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/energy'>Energy</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/industrial'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/industrial'>Industrial</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/marine'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/marine'>Marine</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/medical-technologies'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/medical-technologies'>Medical Technologies</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/tool-manufacturers'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/tool-manufacturers'>Tool Manufacturers</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/mixed-parts'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/mixed-parts'>Mixed Parts</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem selected={pathname === '/home/industry/watch'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesClose} component={Link} to='/home/industry/watch'>Watch</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SimpleMenu);
```

Comment: using URL for govern you logic directly - is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `name` explicitly on each `MenuItem`.

`MenuListProps` does apply to inner `MenuList` component only, not to `MenuItem`s.

### ...

But, in your case I'd not use name prop, just set it in `setState` directly:

```
handleIndustriesSelect = event => {
  this.setState({ industry: event.target.value });
```

### ...

Also, it looks like `e.target.value` is also `undefined`, if so is true for you, then you have to pass `value` prop too, which is a sign of overcomplication.

Comment: OK thanks, I did that by wrapping the MenuItems in a MenuList and using MenuListProps, but I get a warning that "React does not recognize the MenuListProps" prop on a DOM element.

 <MenuList
            MenuListProps={{
              name: 'industry'
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'aerospace'} name={'industry'} selected={this.state.industry === 'aerospace'} onClick={this.handleIndustriesSelect} component={Link} to='/home/industry/aerospace'>Aerospace</MenuItem></MenuList>

Comment: Because `MenuListProps` will pass these props to the DOM element - which is `<ul>` basically. Why use `MenuListProps` or `MenuList` at all? Take a look at example [here in docs](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#selected-menus)